# DUMMY OUTPUT LUBUNTU

Tags: sound

I was watching a video and then I reboot my pc and closed it and on next day I opened a video there was no sound then I opened pulseaudio and in output it's showed "DUMMY OUTPUT"
I tried everything on google but it did't fixed I opened audiomixer but it's did't work I also tried pulseaudio -k and many other but it's not working and my headphones are also not working  please help me.

Comment: I am confused. You say rebooted and closed. Did you not shut it down correctly? Also why reboot it first?